# Is it possible to make dir recursive in macOS using terminal

Tags: terminal

I have tried using this command but it seems not to work:

```
> mkdir -R /data/k8s/reddwarf-pro/cv-server-service/cv/img/
mkdir: illegal option -- R
usage: mkdir [-pv] [-m mode] directory_name ...
```

Comment: What do you mean “make a directory recursive”?  Do the child directories exist up to where you want to make your new directory?

Comment: Are you just trying to create `folder/folder/folder/folder/folder` ?? Use the `-p` flag, as per the man page. Also, is data really at the root level? If not, don't have a leading `/`

Comment: I'm curious, which documentation did you find the `-R` flag in?

Comment: r is recursive shortcut.

Comment: There is no standardized meaning for options. `-r` is recursive for `cp`, for `bash` it means "restricted shell", for `tar` it appends files to an existing archive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To create several levels of directories, use `-p`

```
mkdir -p ~/foo/A
```

You can also combine it with brace expansions to create several hierarchies at once:

```
mkdir -p ~/bar/{one,two,three}
mkdir -p ~/{one,two,three}/foo
```

Comment: The `-p` flag can also be applied to `rmdir` to perform the inverse action (aka undo): `rmdir -p ~/foo/A`